# GNU Makefile : How to use pattern-rule adding a compilation flag to a match-anything pattern-rule by using pattern-specific variable value?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have created several test files `test_*.c`, each testing a single function of a c library I built.

I first wrote a Makefile for compiling each c file to produce its corresponding binary:

```
TEST_SRCS       =   ${wildcard *.c}

TEST_EXECS      =   ${TEST_SRCS:.c=}

PROJECT_PATH    =   ../my_project

CFLAGS          =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror

%::         %.c ${PROJECT_PATH}/libmyproject.a
            gcc ${CFLAGS} $< -L${PROJECT_PATH} -lmyproject -o $@

all:        ${TEST_EXECS}

clean:
            rm -f ${TEST_EXECS}

re:         clean all

.PHONY:     all clean re
```

This works as expected, so when i type `make test_<name_of_my_function>` and if the 'test_<name_of_my_function>.c' file exists, it compiles it to create the 'test_<name_of_my_function>' binary.

**But now i want to add a rule that creates the binary in debug mode by adding the gcc flag `-g` to the command if i run the command `make debug_test_<name_of_my_function>`.**

I tried adding the pattern-specific rule `debug_%` and use a pattern-specific value for appending `-g` to `CFLAGS`:

```
TEST_SRCS       =   ${wildcard *.c}

TEST_EXECS      =   ${TEST_SRCS:.c=}

PROJECT_PATH    =   ../my_project

CFLAGS          =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror

%::         %.c ${PROJECT_PATH}/libmyproject.a
            gcc ${CFLAGS} $< -L${PROJECT_PATH} -lmyproject -o $@

all:        ${TEST_EXECS}

debug_%:    CFLAGS += -g
debug_%:    %

clean:
            rm -f ${TEST_EXECS}

re:         clean all

.PHONY:     all clean re
```

But when i run for example `debug_test_function1`, i get the following ouptut :

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'debug_test_function1'.  Stop.
```

*Note that whatever prerequisite rule i use for the target `debug_%`, it isn't executed (even if the prerequisite is not a pattern rule).*

*Note also that if i replace in the makefile*

```
debug_%:    CFLAGS += -g
debug_%:    %
```

*by*

```
debug%:     %.c ${PROJECT_PATH}/libft.a
            gcc ${CFLAGS} -g $< -L${PROJECT_PATH} -lmyproject -o $@
```

*it works. But i'd lose the benefit of using a pattern-specific variable here.*

Any clue oh how to use pattern-specific variable values to do it?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I would create different executables for non-debug and debug versions, as your resort does. Otherwise you have two ways leading to the same target, and later you cannot see which way you chose. -- Anyway, why don't you create your test programs always in debug mode? I always preferred non-optimized test programs in debug versions, for easier debugging. The gain in size and speed is negligible for test programs. The object under test can be optimized and non-debug, as black-box tests are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
debug_%:    %
```

does not define a pattern rule.  It *deletes* a pattern rule.  See [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).  So, you've not defined any rules here that know how to build `debug_test_function1` (because there's no file `debug_test_function1.c` to build it from and the only rule you have available is the match-anything rule).

You have to provide the recipe here, you *cannot* omit it.  But obviously you can still add a pattern-specific variable; why not?:

```
debug_%:    CFLAGS += -g
debug_%:    %.c ${PROJECT_PATH}/libft.a
        gcc ${CFLAGS} $< -L${PROJECT_PATH} -lmyproject -o $@
```

I'm not really sure what "benefit of pattern-specific variables" you are referring to since you don't seem to build an other prerequisites that need to inherit the pattern-specific variable.  But the above should work.

Comment: Ok thank you for your clear answer ! I misinterpreted the manual as i thought we could read this rule as "if i type `make debug_test_function1` -> execute the match-anything pattern rule but with an additional flag `-g`", and did not think that this would override an implicit rule (as for me there is no implicit rule with a target `debug_%`).

By "benefit of pattern-specific variables" i was only hoping to have shorter code in my makefile (but i think i was missing the real goal and interest about those pattern-specific variables) so you're right, it's no big deal using my other solution.

Comment: You could interpret it that way, if it were possible to create a pattern rule with no recipe.  But, as per the manual a pattern rule with no recipe tells make to cancel that pattern rule (turn it off) if it exists.  If it doesn't exist, it's a no-op (you can't cancel a pattern rule that doesn't exist).  As a result, you can't create "chains" of pattern rules with no recipes.